# dompdf not rendering images properly

Tags: image, render, dompdf

I'm rendering HTML content into PDF using dompdf, but having issue with one image which is not rendering correctly. In PDF one image starts to load but ends in askew half loading position.

[Brown image with ornaments shoud be loaded as image displayed below](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/8827/xi14.jpg)

I have already tried to change pictures and switch hosting.

Any ideas on this issue?
Many thanks

EDIT -----

**DOMPDF SETTINGS**

```
$url = "http://www.profitemplate.com/pdf/cal/testImg.php";
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
// In points
$paperSize = array(0, 0, 456.5, 1364.1);

$dompdf->set_paper($paperSize);
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

**HTML can be foud on**: profitemplate.com/pdf/cal/testImg.php

**Generated PDF:** [LINK](http://profitemplate.com/pdf/cal/index.php) - it takes a while to load so it's better to download it ..

**

> LINKS DEAD (27.08.2013)

**

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see where you might need to modify it?

Comment: Soryy i've added my code and links to PDFs now ..

Comment: what version of dompdf are you using?

Comment: also are all the images on the same host as the script or external?

Comment: Can't find version number but i've got this https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf. 

All images are on the same host as script ..

Comment: Can I see the code for the html file too? at least the part with the images?

Comment: HTML is on: http://www.profitemplate.com/pdf/cal/testImg.php just see source code of that page. File is called "testImg.php" but there is only HTML.

Comment: Seems all ok to me. Have you tried the same page but with smaller image dimensions ?

Comment: The problem is that i need large dimensions. On the other side it's realy strange because when i use one large image everyting is going fine. HTML: http://www.profitemplate.com/pdf/cal/testImg2.php | PDF: http://www.profitemplate.com/pdf/cal/index2.php

Comment: It seems a bit worse on the latest code, you might try 0.6.0 beta 3. You might also try converting to another format. Hard to tell without further investigation into the issue, but something could be going wrong while processing the image. Try converting to PNG and see if that helps.

Comment: Never mind, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to stem from a bug in how dompdf handles border-radius. If certain corners have no border radius set while other do then dompdf miscalculates the boundaries of the box border. The mask applied to the content is only partially drawn and ends up covering some of the content.

I'm not yet sure of the exact parameters that cause this to happen, but you can work around the issue with a 1px border radius instead of 0px on corners where you want no border radius. Not exactly a square border but it shouldn't be noticeable.

Border radius is still a work-in-progress. You can follow its status and report bugs in the implementation in the issue tracker: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/374. (I've already made note of this issue.)

Comment: thanks, this helped. I've removed-border radius and used z-index for background instead :)